# End of url and nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm using following nginx rewrite rule and I don't understand why next results.

```
server {
    server_name old.example.com;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    rewrite ^/.*-f(\d+)/.*-t(\d+)\.html$ https://new.example.com/view.php?f=$1&t=$2 permanent;
}
```

The following result is ok (the url ends with '.html').

```
$ curl --head "http://old.example.com/abcd-f15/efgh-t125.html"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.17.6
Date: Sat, 02 May 2020 12:48:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://new.example.com/view.php?f=15&t=125
```

The following result is also ok (the url doesn't ends with '.html').

```
$ curl --head "http://old.example.com/abcd-f15/efgh-t125.htmlx"
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.17.6
Date: Sat, 02 May 2020 12:50:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 153
Connection: keep-alive
```

But I don't understand the following result (the url doesn't ends with '.html' but rewrite rule is matched).

```
$ curl --head "http://old.example.com/abcd-f15/efgh-t125.html#x"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.17.6
Date: Sat, 02 May 2020 12:51:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://new.example.com/view.php?f=15&t=125
```

Comment: The `#x` is the [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) and is not seen by the server.

Comment: OK I understand. So this fragment can't be redirected ? Something like `http://old.example.com/view.php#1 -> http://new.example.com/view.php#1` isn't possible ? We must only have `http://old.example.com/view.php#1 -> http://new.example.com/view.php` ?

Comment: In my answer, I've explained how the *fragment* is preserved by the client and you don't have to worry about it on your server-side redirection if it isn't supposed to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the [RFC 3986, 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) regarding the URL syntax:

> ```
>      foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
>      \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
>       |           |            |            |        |
>    scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
>       |   _____________________|__
>      / \ /                        \
>      urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
> ```

We are interested in the *fragment*, and it's defined in the [section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5):

> Fragment identifiers have a special role in information retrieval
> systems as the primary form of client-side indirect referencing,
> allowing an author to specifically identify aspects of an existing
> resource that are only indirectly provided by the resource owner. As
> such, the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
> processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
> solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.

**TL;DR: The processing of the HTTP URL *fragment* `#x` happens on the client side alone.**

Let's add some verbosity to your `curl` with a `-v` and we can see this more clearly:

```
$ curl --head "http://old.example.com/abcd-f15/efgh-t125.html#x"

> HEAD /abcd-f15/efgh-t125.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: old.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.17.6
< Date: Sat, 02 May 2020 12:51:53 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 169
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://new.example.com/view.php?f=15&t=125
```

I believe from this you can already deduce why this is the expected behaviour for your `rewrite`.

---

**What happens to the fragment after the redirect?** Unless your `Location:` header exclusively specifies a new fragment, the client (web browser) preserves it per [RFC 7231, 7.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2):

> If the `Location` value provided in a `3xx` (Redirection) response does
> not have a fragment component, a user agent MUST process the
> redirection as if the value inherits the fragment component of the
> URI reference used to generate the request target (i.e., the
> redirection inherits the original reference's fragment, if any).

In short, for URL `http://old.example.com/abcd-f15/efgh-t125.html#x`:

- If the `Location` doesn't specify a new fragment (the current situation):

  ```
    > GET /abcd-f15/efgh-t125.html
    > Host: old.example.com
    < Location: https://new.example.com/view.php?f=15&t=125
  ```

  -> `https://new.example.com/view.php?f=15&t=125#x`
- If you added a fragment `y` to your `rewrite` rule:

  ```
    > GET /abcd-f15/efgh-t125.html
    > Host: old.example.com
    < Location: https://new.example.com/view.php?f=15&t=125#y
  ```

  -> `https://new.example.com/view.php?f=15&t=125#y`
- The new HTTP request doesn't contain the fragment, either, so it's same for both:

  ```
    > GET /view.php?f=15&t=125
    > Host: new.example.com
  ```